# Convert micros to currency in AWQL csv report with Adwords API

Tags: php, csv, google-ads-api, adwords-budgetservice

I have this query in AWQL and I get the response in CSV format using the [ReportUtils::DownloadReportWithAwql](http://googleads.github.io/googleads-php-lib/AdWords/files/AdWords.Util.ReportUtils.html#%5CReportUtils::DownloadReportWithAwql())

```
select Date, Clicks, Cost from ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT during LAST_30_DAYS
```

I need to convert the **Cost data in the CSV from micros to the currency** in the account (Cost / 1000000).

Also I need to be able to convert any the **Cost** data in the response using **any** AWQL query, for example the solution has to work for this query also:

```
SELECT CampaignName, KeywordText, Cost, CostPerConversion, QualityScore FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING LAST_7_DAYS
```

As of v201406, the returnMoneyInMicros header is no longer valid and values are always returned as micros. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting-concepts#money

*This is my first question in stackoverflow.*

Comment: @drep I make the 2 queries and the result are [here](https://gist.github.com/mayeco/1904e3d8243c62a129ea) now imagine you have cost1 in a $variable1 and cost2 in $variable2. how do I divide by 1000000 the Cost and Cost/conversion columns in the variables using the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it and works great for me.

```
    //data is a string with data in micros in csv format
    $data = $this->DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwql($awql);

    //start micros conversion
    $count = 0;
    $costpos = array();
    $newarray = array();
    foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $data) as $line){

        $linearray = str_getcsv($line);

        if($count == 0) {
            //adwords report title
            $newarray[] = $linearray;
            $count++;
            continue;
        }

        if($count == 1) {
            //columns report header
            $postvalue = 0;

            foreach($linearray as $value){
                if (strpos($value,'Cost') !== false) {
                    $costpos[] = $postvalue;
                }
                $postvalue++;
            }

            $newarray[] = $linearray;
            $count++;
            continue;
        }

        if(!empty($costpos)) {

            foreach($costpos as $costpostval){

                if(isset($linearray[$costpostval])) {
                    $linearray[$costpostval] = $linearray[$costpostval] / 1000000;
                }

            }
        }

        $newarray[] = $linearray;
        $count++;
    }


    $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "FOO");
    $outstream = fopen($tmpfname, "r+");
    foreach($newarray as $newline){
        fputcsv($outstream, $newline);
    }
    fclose($outstream);
    //end micros conversion - $tmpfname temp file with cost in currency csv formated
```